# Duplicate event received on listener when using ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS

Tags: spring, listener, cglib

In some cases, we need to write to database in a Spring -application within an `ApplicationListener`, so we need transactions within the listener using `@Transactional`-annotation. These listeners are extended from an abstract baseclass, so normal `ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES` won't do, as Spring container complains about expecting a bean of the abstract class-type, not "[$Proxy123]". However, using `Scope(proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)`, the listener receives the same event twice. We are using Spring version 3.1.3.RELEASE. (Edit: Still occurring with version 3.2.4.RELEASE)

Digging into Spring source with debugger, I found out that **org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.getApplicationListeners** returns a `LinkedList` that contains the same listener twice (same instance: `[com.example.TestEventListenerImpl@3aa6d0a4, com.example.TestEventListenerImpl@3aa6d0a4]`), if the listener is a `ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS`.

Now, I can work around this by placing the code handling database write into a separate class and putting the `@Transactional` there, but my question is, is this a bug in Spring or expected behavior? Are there any other workarounds so we wouldn't need to create separate service-classes (ie. handle the transaction in the listener, but don't get the same event twice) for even the simplest cases?

Below is a smallish example showing the problem.

With `@Scope(proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)` in TestEventListenerImpl, the output is as follows:

```
Event com.example.TestEvent[source=Main] created by Main
Got event com.example.TestEvent[source=Main]
Got event com.example.TestEvent[source=Main]
```

With `@Scope(proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)` removed from TestEventListenerImpl, the output is:

```
Event com.example.TestEvent[source=Main] created by Main
Got event com.example.TestEvent[source=Main]
```

So it seems that TARGET_CLASS -scoped beans get inserted twice into the listener list.

Example:

*applicationContext.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example/**"/>

</beans>
```

*com.example.TestEvent*

```
public class TestEvent extends ApplicationEvent
{
    public TestEvent(Object source)
    {
        super(source);
        System.out.println("Event " + this + " created by " + source);
    }
}
```

*com.example.TestEventListener*

```
public interface TestEventListener extends ApplicationListener<TestEvent>
{

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(TestEvent event);

}
```

*com.example.TestEventListenerImpl*

```
@Component
@Scope(proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)  //If commented out, the event won't be received twice
public class TestEventListenerImpl implements TestEventListener
{
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(TestEvent event)
    {
        System.out.println("Got event " + event);
    }
}
```

*com.example.ListenerTest*

```
public class ListenerTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:applicationContext.xml");

        SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster eventMulticaster = appContext.getBean(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.class);

        //This is also needed for the bug to reproduce
        TestEventListener listener = appContext.getBean(TestEventListener.class);

        eventMulticaster.multicastEvent(new TestEvent("Main"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it the same instance of the Listener? Great question by the way!

Comment: I ran this and I only get one event.

Comment: Also, nothing is proxied in your example code.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: What Spring version are you using? At least this occurred at work with 3.1.3.RELEASE from Maven. Cannot remember the CGlib version, but I doubt it would have a difference... I'm at home now (wrote the question at work), and currently have only one very old mini laptop to use due to moving in to a new place and renovating, so cannot test this with different versions right now... hopefully they've got it fixed in newer release (if it is indeed a Spring bug, like I suspect).

Comment: I'm on `3.2.4`. Maybe rework the example you want to show us, because the above isn't going to create any proxies, it has no reason to.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: like I said, I cannot test this right now, but will take a second look at it on monday. I did test this example multiple times at work, and the event was received twice on each time the `@Scope(proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)`-annotation was in place. The pom.xml -file had a ton of dependencies, as I ripped it straight from one of our projects, not sure if it has any effect. Also, I'm pretty sure the same *instance* of the listener was listed twice on the listener list that SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster was calling, when checked with debugger.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I now tested this again, and at first didn't get it to reproduce. But, adding the line `TestEventListener listener = appContext.getBean(TestEventListener.class);` to main, it started reproducing again. I originally removed the line (after testing), as it seemed unnecessary (the test does nothing with the bean). My bad, but with this "fix" it seems the bug is reproducible even with version 3.2.4.RELEASE.

Comment: Once @Transactional is involved my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21852474/event-listeners-in-spring-is-called-twice might be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't speak to if this is a bug or expected behavior, but here's the dirty:

Declaring a bean like

```
@Component
@Scope(proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)  //If commented out, the event won't be received twice
public class TestEventListenerImpl implements TestEventListener
{
```

Creates two `BeanDefinition` instances:

1. A `RootBeanDefinition` describing the Scoped bean.
2. A `ScannedGenericBeanDefinition` describing the actual object.

The `ApplicationContext` will use these bean definitions to create two beans:

1. A `ScopedProxyFactoryBean` bean. This is a `FactoryBean` that wraps the `TestEventListenerImpl` object in a proxy.
2. A `TestEventListenerImpl` bean. The actual `TestEventListenerImpl` object.

Part of the initialization process is to register beans that implement the `ApplicationListener` interface. The `TestEventListenerImpl` bean is created eagerly (right away) and registered as an `ApplicationListener`.

The `ScopedProxyFactoryBean` is lazy, the bean (proxy) it's supposed to create is only generated when requested. When that happens, it also gets registered as an `ApplicationListener`. You only see this when you explicitly request it

```
TestEventListener listener = appContext.getBean(TestEventListener.class);
```

Or implicitly by using `@Autowired` to inject it into another bean. Note that the actual target object is added, not the proxy.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! I'll have to check if our listeners are autowired or retrieved from the context somewhere for whatever reason and see if I can work around it, if that could prevent the proxied listeners from being called twice. It's not that big of an issue really, but I'd rather have a listener call a DAO-interface with @Transactional directly in trivial cases (like event triggering a database record update or such) than do the whole listener -> service-interface -> service implementation -> DAO -dance, since it seems just unnecessary boilerplate.

Comment: @esaj I haven't quite understood why you need `@Scope` if it's going to be prototype/singleton anyway.

Comment: In the real use-case, the listeners are derived from an abstract baseclass and some implementations would need to be proxied for the @Transactional-annotations to work. Without proxying, no transaction are created. With "normal" ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES, the application container fails to start, complaining about AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster (or similar) expecting listener-beans of the abstract class-type, and not proxies (like "[$Proxy123]"). With TARGET_CLASS -proxies, everything seemed to work fine, until we noticed the events triggering twice on proxied listeners ;P

Comment: @esaj With the right CGLIB libraries, `@Component` and `@Transactional`, you should get a `ENHANCED_BY_CGLIB` style proxy even without the `@Scope`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've been thinking about something like AOP/load-time code-weaving/whatsitcalled-transactions, but haven't had the time to delve more deeper into it. Currently I guess we'll just have to go with the listener -> service -> DAO -route where needed, as there's a ton of other stuff to do (as usual), but definitely have to take look when I have the chance.