# Event Listeners in spring is called twice

Tags: spring, event-listener

I am an issue with Spring Event Listeners In my Web app, Any immediate help will be appreciated.

**Event Listeners is registered and called twice, If I have cyclic dependency.**

I have service class, this has @transaction annotation on another methods

```
@Service(PBSTaskService.BEAN_NAME)
public class PBSTaskServiceImpl extends StandardServiceImpl<ITask> implements          PBSTaskService,ApplicationListener<SurveyDefinitionPublishedEvent>
{
    @Autowired
    private AutoSelectTaskSliceRouteSyncService autoSelectTaskSliceRouteSyncService; //  CYCLIC Dependency
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(SurveyDefinitionPublishedEvent event)
     { 
      System.out.println("PBSTSImpl"); // THIS IS CALLED TWICE
     }
... Other method with @Transaction Annotation
}


@Service(AutoSelectTaskSliceRouteSyncService.BEAN_NAME)
public class AutoSelectTaskSliceRouteSyncServiceImpl implements AutoSelectTaskSliceRouteSyncService
{ 
      @Autowired private PBSTaskService pbsTaskService; // CYCLIC dependency
}
```

Now If I remove AutoSelectTaskSliceRouteSyncService dependency from First Class, OnApplicationEvent is called once, else twice.

I debugged and found out that 
SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.getApplicationListeners(myEvent) : Has two proxy object, one wrapped with Cglib and another default one. But it has two only in case if it has cyclic dependency. If I remove Cyclic dependency, it has only one proxy object and that one is enahnces by CGLIB.
my Tx annotation : 
 I had tried it with proxy-target-class="true or false" but no luck.

You may want to have a look on

https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7940?focusedCommentId=98988&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-98988

Answer (score 6):

Since Spring 4.2 you can do away with implementing ApplicationListener and use the new @EventListener annotation on methods in any managed bean. This should help you avoid any conflicts.

Below is an example from https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2

```
@Component
public class MyListener {

    @EventListener
    public void handleContextRefresh(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I used `@EventListener` instead of  `ApplicationListener` interface.

Answer (score 3):

ApplicationEvent Listeners are called twice at many more places in our web app.  This is one of scenarios that we caught up.

Reason : 
Listeners are registered twice. Two proxy are returned wrapped over one instance of listeners. Proxy returned are 1. Dynamic Jdk Interface proxy 2. Cglib Proxy,  when we have @transactions annotations.

To recreate these three point are must:

1. Your listeners must implements ApplicationListener   2. Your listeners must have cyclic dependency with another class    3.Your listeners must have one method annotated with @Transaction.

I have created a separate project where I am able to reproduce it with spring and hibernate. If 2 and 3 are not present together, then we are safe.

Solution 
               I tried many tweaks with spring and transaction configuration but no luck. Then finally with my demo project when I moved the transaction code to another class, so that the listeners do not have any @transaction annotations then it worked for me.

Comment: Faced with same problem in Grails 2.4.5 when mark service class as ApplicationListener.

Answer (score 3):

In Spring classes anotated with @Service or @Component which implement the ApplicationListener interface are going to receive duplicate events. To resolve the issue, to only receive single events, just remove the @Service or @Compontent annotation.

Answer (score 1):

In a case of circular dependency between Spring beans, Spring Beans machinery **might** (under certain circumstances) place two versions of a same bean, the bean itself and its `Advised` wrapper into the list of `ApplicationListener`s handled by an `ApplicationEventMulticaster`.
You could, however, implement your custom `ApplicationEventMulticaster` and fix this bug (it looks like a bug to me).

In a snippet below a custom implementation subclasses Spring's `SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster`, ignores non-`Advised` duplicate of a bean, and leaves `Advised` version of it in the list of `ApplicationListener`s (most likely you would want an `Advised` version of your `onApplicationEvent` method to be called - in a case it is annotated with `@Transactional` or AOP-advised, but if you need otherwise, the change of algorithm is trivial)

```
@Component
public class AdviceAwareApplicationEventMulticaster extends SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster {

    @Override
    protected Collection<ApplicationListener<?>> getApplicationListeners(ApplicationEvent event, ResolvableType eventType) {
        Map<ApplicationListener<?>, ApplicationListener<?>> listenersByNakedInstances = new LinkedHashMap<>();// because superclass returns sorted listeners
        Collection<ApplicationListener<?>> applicationListeners = super.getApplicationListeners(event, eventType);
        for (ApplicationListener<?> listener : applicationListeners) {
            boolean advised = false;
            ApplicationListener<?> nakedListener = null;
            if (listener instanceof Advised) {
                try {
                    nakedListener = (ApplicationListener<?>) ((Advised)listener).getTargetSource().getTarget();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO 
                }
                advised = true;
            } else
                nakedListener = listener;
            if (advised || !listenersByNakedInstances.containsKey(nakedListener))
                listenersByNakedInstances.put(nakedListener, listener);
        }
        return listenersByNakedInstances.values();
    }
}
```

You don't need to anyhow make your custom implementation known to Spring, it's enough to have it as a Spring bean and Spring Application Context will pick it up.

Also, don't forget that if there are more one Spring Application Contexts in the application, your Listener **might** be called for each of those, but it's altogether different story.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue with one of my services, created another listner with the same event that was only called once.

So what **@SimonH** wrote is **not always the case, only in some circumstances I could not reproduce**:

> In Spring classes anotated with @Service or @Component which implement the ApplicationListener interface are going to receive duplicate events.

In my case this lead to a double call of the **onApplicationEvent** method.

```
@Service
public class TestClass implements ApplicationListener<MyEvent>{

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(MyEvent event){
        // called twice
    }
}
```

**Instead of the code above, I could solve it by creating the Event Listener as an inner class and then call the event method of the parent.**

```
@Service
public class TestClass {

    @Component
    private class MyListener implements ApplicationListener<MyEvent> {

        @Override
        public void onApplicationEvent(MyEvent event) {
            TestClass.this.onApplicationEvent(event);
        }
    }

    public void onApplicationEvent(MyEvent event){
        //Have fun with a single event here
    }
}
```